# Suggestion for enforcing unique constraint in a table where soft delete is implemented

Tags: sql-server, database-design

I am using SQL Server 2014 and in my database, I have a Position table which is structured like this:

```
ID         int           PK
Name       nvarchar(50)  Unique Index
IsDeleted  bit
```

A user can't enter positions with similar names; IsDeleted is a flag for soft delete as I want to avoid deleting records from this table. However it got me thinking in a scenario like this:

```
1. User enters position 'President'.
2. User deletes position 'President'. 
3. User changes mind and again enters a position 'President'.
```

This would result in an error due to unique constraint. Even if I use Name and IsDeleted combination for unique constraint, there is no stopping the user from deleting again and adding several times. One thing I can think of is having Name and TimeStamp combination as unique constraint, but it doesn't sound correct.

I'd like to enforce this if possible in the database, and not the application logic. Can you guys give some suggestions?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but the answer is useful. Add a unique filtered index instead of a constraint.

Comment: And this one with the extended answer in a comment. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/94931/sql-server-unique-index-per-subset-of-data-based-on-values-of-another-column

Comment: You're better off having a position_history table and moving deleted items there

Comment: @Neil McGuigan: Unfortunately, the position ID is used in other tables as FK so I can't move them.

Answer (score 2):

Why not somthing simple like this:

- 1. User enters position 'President' and it does not exist in the table.

     ```
     Insert Into table
     ```
- 2. User deletes position 'President'.

     ```
     Update table set isDeleted = 1
     ```
- 3. User changes mind and again enters a position 'President'.

     ```
     Update table set isDeleted = 0
     ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I also thought of this but in my scenario, this won't do.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE Position (
  Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
  Name nvarchar(255) UNIQUE,
  IsDeleted bit NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
)

INSERT INTO Position (Name) VALUES ('Titi'), ('Toto'), ('Tata')
UPDATE Position set IsDeleted = 1 where Name='Toto'

DECLARE @Name nvarchar(255)
SET @Name = 'Toto'

-- INSERT Position (Name) VALUES (@Name) --RAISES AN ERROR

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Position WHERE Name = @Name) 
  UPDATE Position SET IsDeleted = 0 WHERE Name = @Name
ELSE
    INSERT Position (Name) VALUES (@Name)

SELECT * FROM Position
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, there might be some instances in which the deleted position has some related records via a FK. Now the new position entered should be a fresh one, so this should have no records yet related to it. This query will also bring back related records with it. I need it to be really new while not deleting the old one.

Comment: Ok so as they say, put an unique index on Name and isDeleted = 0 so it will break the unicity and thus raise an error if you try to add the same name with the delete flag set to false. Damn simple !

Comment: As I stated in my original question: "Even if I use Name and IsDeleted combination for unique constraint, there is no stopping the user from deleting again and adding several times". So this will not really work.

Comment: So when a user deletes "President" (id = 5) you update isDeleted to 1, foreign keys with id = 5 remain. Then the user re-enters "President" you can either unflag the existing item (id = 5) by updating isDeleted to 0 or, re-create an item "President" with a new id. Do you see a third option ?